# Why are my forest areas orange and non-forest areas green in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, ndvi, image-classification

I'm doing GEARS' 3rd lab [tutorial](https://www.gears-lab.com/intro_rs_lab3/) on Remote Sensing in Google Earth Engine.

I calculated the NDVI of an area in Batchellor, Australia. The result is a black and white image so I added a color palette. I used [GEE's palette](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_visualization#rendering-categorical-maps) to add color to the NDVI layer and visualize vegetation.

```
// Define a palette for the 18 distinct land cover classes.
var igbpPalette = [
  'aec3d4', // water
  '152106', '225129', '369b47', '30eb5b', '387242', // forest
  '6a2325', 'c3aa69', 'b76031', 'd9903d', '91af40',  // shrub, grass
  '111149', // wetlands
  'cdb33b', // croplands
  'cc0013', // urban
  '33280d', // crop mosaic
  'd7cdcc', // snow and ice
  'f7e084', // barren
  '6f6f6f'  // tundra
];
```

Result is this. Notice the \-shaped chunk of land on the left side, in the colored image, it is green while the surrounding forests are orange.

True color image
[image]

With color pallete
[image]

Here's my whole code in GEE

```
var image = ee.Image(sent2
.filterDate("2018-05-01", "2018-05-31")
.filterBounds(park)
.sort("CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT")
.first());
print("Sentinel-2 scene (May):", image);

var trueColor = {
  bands: ["B4", "B3", "B2"],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000
  };
  
Map.addLayer(image, trueColor, "true color image")

var falseColor = {
  bands: ["B8", "B3", "B2"],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000
  };
  
Map.addLayer(image, falseColor, "false color image")

var NDVI = image.expression(
  "(NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED)",
  {
    RED: image.select("B4"), 
    NIR: image.select("B8"),
    BLUE: image.select("B2")
  });

var igbpPalette = [
  'aec3d4', // water
  '152106', '225129', '369b47', '30eb5b', '387242', // forest
  '6a2325', 'c3aa69', 'b76031', 'd9903d', '91af40',  // shrub, grass
  '111149', // wetlands
  'cdb33b', // croplands
  'cc0013', // urban
  '33280d', // crop mosaic
  'd7cdcc', // snow and ice
  'f7e084', // barren
  '6f6f6f'  // tundra
];

Map.addLayer(NDVI, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: igbpPalette}, "NDVI")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The palette you're using is probably made for a land-cover map with 18 classes, pixel values for instance being integers from 1 to 18. In your case, you have continuous NDVI values. The [docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_visualization#color-palettes) says:

> [...] min and max parameters indicate the range of pixel values to
> which the palette should be applied. Intermediate values are linearly
> stretched.

You could use a palette like this, for instance:

```
var igbpPalette = [
  'red', 'white', 'green'
]
```

This will give you a white pixels for NDVI in the middle of your range (0.5, as your set min to 0 and max of 1). Lower than that will give you more and more red, higher than that will give you more and more green.